# Wagtail | ChoiceField not displayed

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am facing some kind of incomprehensible behavior working with "StructBlock" and "ChoiceBlock". For some reasons the ChoiceBlock dont show up in admin-menu if designed via class-notation.

Like that no choiceblock is shown at admin-menu. Only the textblock.

```
class CodeBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    code = blocks.TextBlock(required=True)
    type = blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[
        ('markup', 'markup'), ('css', 'css')
    ], required=True),

    class Meta:
        template = 'home/blocks/code.html'

class HomePageIndex(Page):
    body = StreamField([('code', CodeBlock())])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

The following solution is in my opinion pretty much equal, but works well. I do not get why... Due the fact i need the Struct-Field more often i prefer the the class-notation.

```
class HomePageIndex(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('code', blocks.StructBlock([
            ('code', blocks.TextBlock(required=True)),
            ('type', blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[
                ('markup', 'markup'), ('css', 'css')
        ], template='home/blocks/code.html'))
])

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    StreamFieldPanel('body'),
```

Not get me wrong, i could make it work (using the bad-way). I wonder why that happens.

Ty in advance

Comment: You have a trailing comma at the end of your `type` definition in the `CodeBlock` class, which means that `type` is saved as a tuple instead of a `ChoiceBlock`. That is why it will not get rendered - because Wagtail doesn't recognise it as a field.

Comment: Ty. That solves my Problem. Tyvm

Comment: Can this be turned into an actual answer and be accepted?

Comment: Works well, as already mentioned.